# passing parameter in mdx query

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, mdx

What I am trying to do is; User would select value of region from the dropdown(Region1, Region2, Region3).
@Region should take that value in the mdx query. 
for eg. if user selects Region2, it should look like: [Region].**[Region2]**.children. The query that I have written shows that there's a syntax error.

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [measures].[region] AS 
    StrToMember("[Region].[" + @Region + "]").CurrentMember.Name 
  MEMBER [measures].[product] AS 
    [Product Line].[product Line L2].CurrentMember.Name 
SELECT 
  NonEmpty
  (
      StrToMember("[Region].[" + @Region + "]").Children
    * 
      [Product Line].[Product Line L2].Children
   ,[Measures].[Total Clients]
  ) ON ROWS
 ,{
    [measures].[region]
   ,[measures].[product]
   ,[Measures].[Total Clients]
  } ON COLUMNS
FROM [EQ Coverage];
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have available the function `strToSet` so this:

```
StrToMember("[Region].[" + @Region + "]").Children
```

Could be written as:

```
StrToSet("[Region].[" + @Region + "].Children", CONSTRAINED)
```

BUT I'm unsure of the purpose of this part of your code?

```
MEMBER [measures].[region] AS 
  StrToMember("[Region].[" + @Region + "]").CurrentMember.Name
```

I don't see the purpose of using the parameter - you could do something like this?

```
MEMBER [measures].[region] AS 
   [Region].[Region].CurrentMember.member_caption
```